# How to fix "... is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm passing down a state setter to a child (from App to Nav), but when I'm calling it I'm getting TypeError: ... is not a function.

How should I fix it? What should I do?

App:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

/* Component imports */
import Nav from './components/nav/nav';
import Container from './components/container/container';

/*------------------*/

function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState("home");

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(appState);
    }, [appState])

  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <Nav state={setAppState}/>
      <Container stateSetter={appState}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nav:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './nav.css';

/* Component imports */



/*------------------*/

function Nav(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="Nav" id="nav">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><button><span>App</span></button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("home")}>Home</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("products")}>Products</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("about_us")}>About Us</button></li>
                        <li><button onClick={() => props.stateSetter("log_in")}>Log in</button></li> 
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

Container:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './conatiner.css';

/* Component imports */



/*------------------*/

function Container(props) {

    const [cont_appState] = useState(props.state);

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [cont_appState])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Container;
```

I just started working an this project, I am also new to react, sorry for my messy code.

[image]

I have to add text to be able to post is: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam placeat atque ipsa eius facilis! Quidem ad officia architecto molestias! Autem molestias molestiae deserunt tempore maxime delectus commodi cum blanditiis inventore?

Comment: What isn't a function? You left off an important part of the error message.

Comment: Your code works just fine, could you answer @SpencerWieczorek question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo

Instead of

```
<Nav state={setAppState} />
```

It should be

```
<Nav stateSetter={setAppState} />
```

Where is the full component

```
function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState("home");

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(appState);
    }, [appState])

  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <Nav stateSetter={setAppState}/>
      <Container stateSetter={setAppState}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you both your time an patient! :)